# How can I click a pushButton on my PyQt5 code and allow it to execute/run another .py file?

Tags: python, qt, button, pyqt, pyqt5

I need help in linking a pushButton on my PyQt5 code so that it runs another .py file automatically.

I have tried using 'self.pushButton.clicked.connect' but this does not seem to work on PyQt5 code. I have attached the code for both my .py files below:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(519, 354)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above code should produce a window with a single button. When that button is clicked it should execute/run the code below

**algorithm.py**

```
arrNumbers = []
i = 0
j = 0
n = 0
a = 0
sum = 0
temp = 0
print("How many numbers would you like to sort?:", end=' ')
n = eval(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    print("Enter Number", i + 1, ":", end=' ')
    a = eval(input())
    arrNumbers.append(a)
for i in range(1, n):
for j in range(0, n - i):
    if (arrNumbers[j] > arrNumbers[j + 1]):
        temp = arrNumbers[j]
        arrNumbers[j] = arrNumbers[j + 1]
        arrNumbers[j + 1] = temp
    print()
    print("After pass:",i)
    for k in range(0, n):
    print(arrNumbers[k], end=' ')
    print("[",i + 1, "biggest number(s) is(are) pushed to the end of the list ]")
print()
print("It was completed in",i,"passes")
print("The sorted list using Bubble Sort is: ", end=' ')
for i in range(0, n):
    print(arrNumbers[i], end=' ')
```

Please can you help me with this issue. I have been searching for solutions but nothing has seemed to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**main.py**

step 1: you need to import your algorithm.py. to do that this is the syntax: `import filename` you can neglect the `.py`

step 2: connect the push button to the function that will call the processes in algorithm.py. this is the syntax: `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.FuncName)`

step 3: call the function in algorithm.py that will do the work. syntax: `filename.FuncInFilename()`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import algorithm

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(519, 354)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenClick)

    def OpenClick(self):
        algorithm.FunctionAlgo()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**algorithm.py** (i added the function `FunctionAlgo()` for this file because it is more proper and it will be easier)

```
def FunctionAlgo():
    arrNumbers = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    n = 0
    a = 0
    sum = 0
    temp = 0
    print("How many numbers would you like to sort?:", end=' ')
    n = eval(input())
    for i in range(0, n):
        print("Enter Number", i + 1, ":", end=' ')
        a = eval(input())
        arrNumbers.append(a)
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(0, n - i):
            if (arrNumbers[j] > arrNumbers[j + 1]):
                temp = arrNumbers[j]
                arrNumbers[j] = arrNumbers[j + 1]
                arrNumbers[j + 1] = temp
            print()
            print("After pass:",i)
            for k in range(0, n):
                print(arrNumbers[k], end=' ')
                print("[",i + 1, "biggest number(s) is(are) pushed to the end of the list ]")
    print()
    print("It was completed in",i,"passes")
    print("The sorted list using Bubble Sort is: ", end=' ')
    for i in range(0, n):
        print(arrNumbers[i], end=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, works great! Just one more thing. When  I click the pushButton, I would like the program to bring the Python Shell at the very front of all my windows. That way I do not need to click the button then go back to my Python shell to input my numbers. It will make it easier if the shell was bought to my attention automatically. I hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd like to close the MainWindow when you'll click the push button. If so, use this syntax: `window.close()`. In your case, insert `MainWindow.close()` before `algorithm.FunctionAlgo()`. this closes the widget. Returns true if the widget was closed; otherwise returns false. you can read the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#close)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way but what I would do is put all your code in algorithm.py into a function like so.

```
def main():
    arrNumbers = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    n = 0
    a = 0
    sum = 0
    temp = 0
    print("How many numbers would you like to sort?:", end=' ')
    n = eval(input())
    for i in range(0, n):
        print("Enter Number", i + 1, ":", end=' ')
        a = eval(input())
        arrNumbers.append(a)
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(0, n - i):
            if (arrNumbers[j] > arrNumbers[j + 1]):
                temp = arrNumbers[j]
                arrNumbers[j] = arrNumbers[j + 1]
                arrNumbers[j + 1] = temp
            print()
            print("After pass:",i)
            for k in range(0, n):
            print(arrNumbers[k], end=' ')
            print("[",i + 1, "biggest number(s) is(are) pushed to the end of the list ]")
        print()
    print("It was completed in",i,"passes")
    print("The sorted list using Bubble Sort is: ", end=' ')
    for i in range(0, n):
        print(arrNumbers[i], end=' ')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

then import the code into your main.py like so.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import algorithm

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(519, 354)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        algorithm.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, works great! Just one more thing. When  I click the pushButton, I would like the program to bring the Python Shell at the very front of all my windows. That way I do not need to click the button then go back to my Python shell to input my numbers. It will make it easier if the shell was bought to my attention automatically. I hope that makes sense. Thanks